# Shortest path graph search with conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, maze

The problem is a maze consisting of buildings connected by an annex. The layout of the maze is known completely to the programmer. However, each annex is filled with one of four types of poisonous gases. A gas mask is available that can provide immunity from each type of gas, provided it is fitted with a filter specific to that type of gas. The four filters (one of each type) are each in a given building in the maze.

a) The first goal is to write a method `maze_solver_single_explorer(maze, start, end)` that returns the minimum number of timesteps required to reach `end` from `start`. During each timestep, one may pick up any number of filters located in the same building and then traverse at most one annex (provided that the proper filter is in possession). Attaching or detaching filters from the gas mask may be done instantaneously and as often as needed.

b) The second goal is to write a method `maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, start, end, max_timesteps)` that returns the minimum number of explorers required to reach `end` from `start` within the given time limit (a small constant less than 20). Explorers start from the source building and only one explorer needs to reach the goal building. In addition to the above rules, filters can be dropped for other players to pick up from the same building. Dropping one or multiple filters may be done at the beginning of a timestep, so that an explorer may drop a filter and explore an annex in the same timestep. However, another explorer may not pick up a filter dropped in the same timestep. Example: explorer 0 moves left to pick up filter 0 and at the same time explorer 1 moves right to pick up filter 1. Both then return to the source building and explorer 0 picks up filter 1 dropped by explorer 1 and continue the journey to the destination building.

How do I go about modeling/coding this problem in Python?

EDIT: I have written some simple test cases:

```
def test_explore_single_basic(self):
        buildings = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        annexes = [('A', 'B', 0), ('B', 'D', 2), ('B', 'C', 0), ('C', 'D', 3)]
        filters = [('A', 0), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('D', 1)]
        start = 'A'
        goal = 'D'
        labyrinth = Maze(buildings, annexes, filters, start, goal)
        # There are two edges leading to the goal building, D. However the 
        # filter of type 3 cannot be obtained without reaching the goal 
        # building itself. So the explorer must first go to C to pick up the
        # filter of type 2. Thus the fastest sequence of actions is:
        # pick up filter 0, go from A to B, go from B to C, pick up filter 2, 
        # go from C to B, go from B to D.
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_single_explorer(maze), 4)

def test_explore_single_unreachable(self):
        # Same as the previous test, except we require filter type 3 to go
        # from B to D.
        buildings = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        annexes = [('A', 'B', 0), ('B', 'D', 3), ('B', 'C', 0), ('C', 'D', 3)]
        filters = [('A', 0), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('D', 1)]
        start = 'A'
        goal = 'D'
        maze = Maze(buildings, annexes, filters, start, goal)
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_single_explorer(maze), None)

def test_explore_multiple_basic(self):
        #   L  --  S  --  R
        #          |
        #          D
        #          |
        #          G
        buildings = ['S', 'L', 'R', 'D', 'G']
        annexes = [('S', 'L', 0), ('S', 'R', 1), ('S', 'D', 2), ('D', 'G', 3)]
        filters = [('S', 0), ('S', 1), ('R', 2), ('L', 3)]
        start = 'S'
        goal = 'G'
        maze = Maze(buildings, annexes, filters, start, goal)
        # A single explorer needs 6 timesteps to get to the goal.
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, 20), 1)
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, 6), 1)
        # Two explorers can make it in 5 timesteps. One explorer goes right, 
        # picks up filter 2, goes back and drops it at S.
        # Meanwhile, the other explorer goes left, picks up filter 3, goes 
        # back to S, picks up filter 2, and finally proceeds to D and G.
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, 5), 2)
        # No matter how many explorers you have, it's not possible to reach
        # the goal in 4 or fewer timesteps.
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, 4), None)

def test_explore_multiple_unreachable(self):
        # Same as the previous test, except filter type 2 is unreachable.
        buildings = ['S', 'L', 'R', 'D', 'G']
        annexes = [('S', 'L', 0), ('S', 'R', 1), ('S', 'D', 2), ('D', 'G', 3)]
        filters = [('S', 0), ('S', 1), ('D', 2), ('L', 3)]
        start = 'S'
        goal = 'G'
        maze = Maze(buildings, annexes, filters, start, goal)
        self.assertEqual(maze_solver_multiple_explorers(maze, 18), None)
```

Comment: I have tried creating an directed graph where each building is a vertex and each annex is a bi-directed edge and ran Dijkstra's on it, but I can't get it to satisfy the filter requirement, nor get it to pick the required ones up before traversing the shortest path to the goal.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

Dijkstra's algorithm is a good approach. However, you need to make your state representation more complete. In addition to just modelling the explorer's position, you also need to model which filters the explorer is carrying.

- For example, you'd start in position: 
  `{x: 0, y: 0, filters: []}`
- Your possible moves would be: 
  `['left', 'right', 'up', 'down']`, (assuming that all the paths exist and none are blocked by a gas).
- Let's say we pick `up`, and that there's a filter there. Your new state would be
  `{x: 0, y: 1, filters: ['S']}`
- Now we know that we can go through paths with gas `S`, but no others.

#### Problem 2

The second problem is much more complex. To do it optimally, you'd need to use some sort of many-agent pathfinding, but it's difficult to solve. It might be doable with a greedy best-first search if you have a good heuristic.